# Term store navigation changes depending on the page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, term-store

In SharePoint 2013, I created a managed metadata navigation system.
Structure is like:

Header1(SiteCollection)
Header2(SiteCollection/Pages/Page.aspx)
-OtherPage2(SiteCollection/Pages/Page2.aspx)
-OtherPage3(SiteCollection/Pages/Page3.aspx)
Header3(SiteCollection/Pages/Page4.aspx)

When I navigate to Other Page 2 or Other Page 3, the navigation changes from the above to:
Other Page2(Becomes a Header)
Other Page3(Becomes a Header)

It seems that when navigating to a child item the menu changes to show the menu based on context. Thus, you do not have a consistent navigation throughout the site, you have a contextual navigation. I want consistency. Am I missing a setting?
Images as reference:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created another navigation system on a different site.  When I did this, instead of using a full url, http://webapp.com/sites/sitecollectino/pages/page.aspx, I used a shortened URL: /sites/sitecollection/pages/page.aspx and the issue went away.
Subsequently changing all the URLs above, made the navigation consistent.